# How to use ObservableObject for interlinked properties?

Tags: xamarin, mvvm, maui, observableobject, xamarin-community-toolkit

I am trying to convert this working view model to one using `ObservableObject` from Community Toolkit to reduce boilerplate.

```
public class HslVM : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private float hue, saturation, luminosity;
    private Color color = default!;

    public float Hue
    {
        get => hue;
        set
        {
            if (hue != value)
                Color = Color.FromHsla(value, saturation, luminosity);
        }
    }


    public float Saturation
    {
        get => saturation;
        set
        {
            if (saturation != value)
                Color = Color.FromHsla(hue, value, luminosity);
        }
    }

    public float Luminosity
    {
        get => luminosity;
        set
        {
            if (luminosity != value)
                Color = Color.FromHsla(hue, saturation, value);
        }
    }

    public Color Color
    {
        get => color;
        set
        {
            if (color == value) return;

            color = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();


            if (hue != color.GetHue())
            {
                hue = color.GetHue();
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Hue));
            }

            if (saturation != color.GetSaturation())
            {
                saturation = color.GetSaturation();
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Saturation));
            }

            if (luminosity != color.GetLuminosity())
            {
                luminosity = color.GetLuminosity();
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Luminosity));
            }
        }
    }


    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;
    private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string name = "")
        => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
}
```

My attempt below does not work.

```
public partial class HslVM : ObservableObject
{
    [ObservableProperty]
    [NotifyPropertyChangedFor(nameof(Color))]
    float hue;


    [ObservableProperty]
    [NotifyPropertyChangedFor(nameof(Color))]
    float saturation;


    [ObservableProperty]
    [NotifyPropertyChangedFor(nameof(Color))]
    float luminosity;


    [ObservableProperty]
    [NotifyPropertyChangedFor(nameof(Hue))]
    [NotifyPropertyChangedFor(nameof(Saturation))]
    [NotifyPropertyChangedFor(nameof(Luminosity))]
    Color color = default!;
}
```

Comment: I don't see `Color = Color.FromHsla(value, saturation, luminosity);` anywhere in the revised code. Nor all the logic in Color setter. ObservableProperty can't do magic; your revised code tells anyone listening that `Color` has changed, BUT it doesn't actually correct the color. Nor, when someone sets Color, does it set the other three values to their corrected values. Am I missing something? IMHO, a situation like this is NOT a good candidate for `ObservableProperty`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets look at [ObservableProperty attribute doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/mvvm/generators/observableproperty), and write the equivalent of your new code:

```cs
[ObservableProperty]
[NotifyPropertyChangedFor(nameof(Color))]
float hue;

[ObservableProperty]
[NotifyPropertyChangedFor(nameof(Hue))]
[NotifyPropertyChangedFor(nameof(Saturation))]
[NotifyPropertyChangedFor(nameof(Luminosity))]
Color color = default!;
```

generates properties something like this:

```cs
public float Hue
{
  get => hue;
  set {
    if (SetProperty(ref hue, value))
      OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Color);
  }
}

public Color Color
{
  get => color;
  set {
    if (SetProperty(ref color, value))
    {
      OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Hue));
      OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Saturation));
      OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Value));
    }
  }
}
```

Compare that to your original working version. Its missing all the "smarts" in the setters, that set the correct values of other fields.

All `ObservableProperty` does is generate that simple "default" property implementation. That isn't useful in this situation. AFAIK, it lacks any way to "inject" the needed smarts.

You might be tempted to keep `Color` setter from original, and change the others to ObservableProperty. That won't work either. `OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Color))`, or the equivalent attribute `NotifyPropertyChangedFor(nameof(Color))` cannot tell Color HOW to update; it can only tell anyone listening that `Color` has changed. That won't correct the color.